# Laravel json response is missing right square bracket and ajax throws parseerror

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-9

View

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/company/ajaxGetClients/1',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); // Expecting this response logged in console.
            },
            error: function (a, e){
                console.log(e); // This logs "parseerror".
            }
        })
```

CompanyController

```
public function ajaxGetClients($id)
{
    return response(Company::findOrFail($id)->clients->toArray()); // versions without toArray() or with toJson() also does not work. response()->json() same result.
}
```

Response

```
[{"id":1,"name":"John","company_id":1,"phone":null,"email":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

As you can see, response is missing ending bracket `]` making json invalid and ajax fails to parse it. Is it a bug in Laravel 9.15 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Parenthesis: `)` Bracket: `]` Brace: `}`

Comment: It would be very odd for data to be malformed like that. Are you sure it's not being truncated for other reasons?

Comment: @isherwood Nope, if I `dd()` this response in Controller it prints everything fine and the content variable of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse object contains valid json.

Comment: Try returning just `return Company::findOrFail($id)->clients` from controller and see if you get a valid json on frontend.

Comment: @Donkarnash Still same response. 
`[{"id":1,"name":"John","company_id":1,"phone":null,"email":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}`

And what is weird first line of response is emty, see img: [link](https://imgur.com/qyHZYIP)

Comment: Response is getting truncated somehow. Could you try `return response()->json(['data' => Company::findOrFail($id)->clients]);`. Then on javascript side you can  try `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: @Donkarnash Now last brace `{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"John","company_id":1,"phone":null,"email":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]` is missing. It always truncate last character.

Comment: Open up the **Network** inspector tab in browser dev tools and inspect what is the response received, does it contain valid json without any truncation

Comment: It does not. See image I linked in first answer to your comment. Same with modified code.

Comment: Switch to a different browser & check the network tab to see the response. If it's okay then switch back to current browser & disable all extensions and try again to check

Comment: Same result in Edge and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

**They are wrong syntax.. Try this:-**

```
public function ajaxGetClients($id)
{
    return response()->json(Company::findOrFail($id)->clients->toArray()); // versions without toArray() or with toJson() also does not work.
}
```

Comment: Same result, response()->json() does not help.